# Overriding a default value set by the browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

Internet Explorer 10 uses 0 instead of 1 as the initial value for the `flex-shrink` property. You have to manually set `flex-shrink: 1` to each element, or assign a class. How can I automatically set it without assigning it manually or using a class?

Comment: How about `* { flex-shrink: 1 }`?

Comment: @Michael_B I like it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always set a default rule in your stylesheet.

Use the [**universal selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) to apply it to all elements.

```
* { flex-shrink: 1; }
```